# How to generically set property configurations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

```
package com.xenoterracide.rpf.model.abstracts;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenerationTime;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.UUID;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntityBase extends AbstractPersistable<UUID> implements Persistable<UUID> { 
    // AbstractPersistable is a Copy of the Spring Data JPA version testing to see if I can fix this problem, 
    // also bug DATAJPA-622, plan to implement the spring variant if I can get it working with UUID

    @NotNull
    @Override
    @Generated( GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "entityIdGenerator")
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)

    public UUID getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```

here's a final class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characters")
class Character extends AbstractEntityBase {
String name;

@Override
@Column( name = "character_id")

public UUID getId() {
    return super.getId();
}
```

but I get this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of id found in com.xenoterracide.rpf.model.character.Character
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyDuplication(PersistentClass.java:515)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:505)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
```

How can I configured the ID of `AbstractPersistable` to do UUID properly and have the column name I want? whilst using `AbstractPersistable` and preferably not requiring duplicated annotations on my final class

*update* I've managed to do some updates via `@AttributeOverride` but realistically I'm not closer to having a class (or otherwise external to the final class) between AbstractPersistable and the final class that can just do the right thing uuid generation wise. tried moving `@GenericGenerator` to my `package-info.java` but then it stopped recognizing a generate via that name

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characters")
@GenericGenerator( name = "uuid-generator", strategy = "uuid2" )
@AttributeOverride(
    name = "id",
    column = @Column(
            name = "character_id",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false,
            unique = true,
            nullable = false
    ) )
class Character extends AbstractPersistable<UUID> implements Persistable<UUID> {
String name;

protected Character(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
protected Character() {
}

@Id
@Override
@Generated( GenerationTime.ALWAYS )
@GeneratedValue( generator = "uuid-generator" )
public UUID getId() {
    return super.getId();
}

@NotNull
@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
protected String getName() {
    return name;
}

@SuppressWarnings( "unused" )
protected void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You override the id in the final class:

```
@Override
@Column( name = "character_id")
public UUID getId() {
    return super.getId();
}
```

You can just let the inheritance do it! So your final class has to be like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "characters")
class Character extends AbstractEntityBase {
String name;
}
```

the getId() is inherithed from the AbstractEntityBase class. you will have an uuid column and a name one.

UPDATE: 
From Spring :  "AbstractPersistable is a one-stop shop for very basic use cases. The only thing it actually does is setting up default id generation. If you want to customize that, there's nothing you gain from extending the class." 
So your class AbstractEntityBase need to implements directly Persistable and that will correct your issue.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntityBase implements Persistable<UUID> { 

    @Generated( GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "entityIdGenerator")
    @Column( columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    // implements methods like hashcode or equals
    ....
}
```

Comment: is it only possible in the final class? my real problem isn't the `name` but the "generators". `AttributeOverride` makes fixing the name easy (didn't find that till after writing the question). I haven't been able to find a way to extend the Spring class in a generic way to add the generators, without putting it in every final class.

Comment: worth noting that this answer isn't really solving my problem regarding the uuid generation, which I want to make reusable whilst also using AbstractPersistable

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want exactly: if you want to reuse generators and don't have to put multiple times the annotation Id and GenericGenerator, defining an AbstractEntityBase  with theses annotations will be sufficient. And then inheritance will give the Id to the subclass Character (which extends AbstractEntityBase).

Comment: it seems to blow up if AbstractEntityBase extends AbstractPersistable. you seem to continue missing AbstractPersistable, because I don't need to override the column name until the final class, so I get a duplicate property id

Comment: You are totaly right, I have missing the AbstractPersistable! I have updated the answer...